# How to grab a value corresponding to a particular date, if the date is before/after the dates in the table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet table with a number of inventory additions:

```
    Date    | Product | New Units | # Total Units 
 -----------|---------|-----------|--------------- 
  1/11/2017 | Coke    |        14 |            14 
  1/31/2017 | Pepsi   |         6 |             6 
  2/12/2017 | Coke    |         3 |            17 
  3/13/2017 | Coke    |        12 |            29 
  3/13/2017 | Pepsi   |        13 |            19
```

e.g., on Feb 12th 2017, I received 3 new units of Coke, for a total of 17 units. I'd like to be able to say for any given product and any given date, how many units of that product did I have on that date?

For example, given the following list of dates in a separate sheet, based on the data above, I'd hope to see this output:

```
    Date    | Coke | Pepsi 
 -----------|------|------- 
  1/10/2017 |    0 |     0 
  1/11/2017 |   14 |     0 
  2/10/2017 |   14 |     6 
  2/15/2017 |   17 |     6 
  3/15/2017 |   29 |    19
```

Is there a formula or formulas I could use to calculate values for B2:B6 and C2:C6?

Answer (score 1):

paste in **G3** (skip the 1st avail row to avoid **`#REF!`**) then drag down, right and up

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($F3<MIN($A$2:$A), 0, IFERROR(IFERROR(
 QUERY($A$2:$D, 
 "select D where A >= date '"&TEXT($F2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
             and A <= date '"&TEXT($F3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
             and B =  '"&G$1&"' ", 0),
 QUERY($A$2:$D, 
 "select D where A >= date '"&TEXT($F1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
             and A <= date '"&TEXT($F3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
             and B =  '"&G$1&"' ", 0)), 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

paste in **G3** (skip the 1st avail row to avoid **`#REF!`**) then drag down, right and up

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($F2<MIN($A$2:$A), 0, IFERROR(IFERROR(
 QUERY(TO_TEXT({VALUE($A$2:$A), $B$2:$D}), 
 "select Col4 where Col1 >= '"&VALUE($F1)&"' 
                and Col1 <= '"&VALUE($F2)&"' 
                and Col2 =  '"&G$1&"' ", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT({VALUE($A$2:$A), $B$2:$D}), 
 "select Col4 where Col1 >= '"&VALUE(#REF!)&"' 
                and Col1 <= '"&VALUE($F2)&"' 
                and Col2 =  '"&G$1&"' ", 0)), 0)))
```

[image]